# How to increase the index of existing itemArray inside DataRow

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, datatable, c#-3.0

Is there any way to increase the index of existing itemArray inside DataRow. Here is my code

```
foreach (DataRow drOutput in myTable.Rows)                    
{
}
```

I want to add new item in my itemArray. Right now my itemArray has one value

```
itemArray[0]="abc";
```

But how can I increase the itemArray value like this

```
itemArray[0]="abc"; //current value
itemArray[1]="new string"; //inserted values
```

Comment: Why don't you use a list instead. You can, if you really need to, at the end convert the list back into an array with ToArray()

Comment: because i already have code to convert dataTable into excel and right now i am reading some columns from Excel and creating a new row and then exporting into excel

Comment: Sorry, but that confuses me even further. Anyway, you can resize an array with `Array.Resize(ref itemArray, x);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a new column to the `DataTable`, then you can specify the value for that new column.

```
myTable.Columns.Add("someNewColumn", typeof(string));

foreach (DataRow drOutput in myTable.Rows)                    
{
    drOutput[1] = "new string";  // or whatever value you want
}
```